# failed to import sklearn in raspi3b ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn

i'm using python3 in my raspi. and i can't get sklearn to work or import pproperly in a code. i already tried to uninstall all numpy versions on my raspi. then only install numpy in python3 using: **sudo apt-get install python3-numpy** but i can't still get it to work. please help me everyone :(

thank you in advanced

this is the traceback of the error when importing sklearn

```
>>> 

import sklearn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__init__.pxd", line 987, in numpy.import_array
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xb but this version of numpy is 0xa

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 134, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .utils.fixes import signature
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32
  File "sklearn/utils/murmurhash.pyx", line 26, in init sklearn.utils.murmurhash
  File "__init__.pxd", line 989, in numpy.import_array
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```